# How to convert data GB2312 to UTF-8 in java?

Tags: java, mime

if

```
String a = "=?gb2312?B?rtmsMCC2=?= " // is in GB2312 format.
```

I want above String a to UTF-8 format. How do I achieve this in java.

Comment: That string is MIME-header-encoded and in ASCII, which is a subset of UTF-8, so it already is in UTF-8. If you want to convert it to a readable form, perhaps you want to start at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047

Answer (score 2):

That is not GB2312 format, it is a MIME Encoded-Word where the data is encoded using Base64, and that encoded data itself denotes text in character set GB2312. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word

To decode this, you need a decoder which supports RFC2047 MIME Encoded-Word. For example [MimeUtility.decodeWord()](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decodeWord%28java.lang.String%29) in javax.mail

The other option is to parse it entirely yourself, but I would advice against that. However the steps would be:

Given your example `=?gb2312?B?rtmsMCC2=?=`

1. `=?` indicates it is an encoded word
2. `gb2312` indicates that the final data is in gb2312 encoding
3. `?B` indicates they payload is encoded Base64
4. `?` indicates the start of the payload
5. `rtmsMCC2=` is the actual payload (as Base64 encoded data)
6. `?=` indicates the end of the encoded word
7. decode `rtmsMCC2=` using Base64 (it seems to be corrupt, but removing the trailing `=` results in bytes `AE D9 AC 30 20 B6`)
8. convert bytes `AE D9 AC 30 20 B6` using gb2312 encoding (I am not doing it here, because I am having trouble mapping these bytes to actual gb2312 characters).

See also https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047